# Remove sparse terms with Python

Tags: python, nlp

We can use {tm} package in R to remove sparse terms in a DTM/TDM, however, I don't know if there's an equivalent command in any Python package that does the same thing.

Create a DTM with python

```
corpus = [dictionary.doc2bow(text) for text in texts]
```

How can I remove sparse terms then?

so I can use filter_extreme in python, should I change the code like this:

```
dictionary = corpora.Dictionary(dictionary_words)
dictionary.filter_extremes(no_below=3)
corpus = [dictionary.doc2bow(t) for t in dictionary_words]
```

Comment: Do you want to filter uncommon words, appearing less than 2 times for example?

Comment: Yes, that's what I want to do!

Comment: The dictionary you built has a `filter_extremes` method: https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/corpora/dictionary.html#gensim.corpora.dictionary.Dictionary.filter_extremes You can filter it there and build the bag-of-words.